# Force Close App Browser Django ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, django

I'm a beginner in Django and I'm trying to test the registration form that I created on my mobile browser, it's working fine, but every time I force close the browser application on my phone or my phone screen timed out I get [WinError 10054]

I have this on my settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['myip']
```

and I run my server like this

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Error that I get:

```
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Is there something I need to configure, so this error won't show up? Thank you.

Comment: You can ignore the error. In a production setup with a WSGI server it won't show up.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question!